# Using 'reselect' to return desired value for every item in store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

This is my first time creating my own selector and I'm having a hard time getting the syntax right to display the value needed in my component.

The store state for `deviceCount` looks like this:

```
{
  deviceCount: {
    'projectId:ed4b4e40-d4e2-4540-8359-c002526f2793': {
      totalDevices: 1,
      meta: { },
      error: {}
    },
    'projectId:a6293167-ade2-4e22-98f0-70260fcee7f7': {
      totalDevices: 0,
      meta: {
      },
      error: {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm using `mapStateToProps` and `createStructuredSelector` in the component:

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({  // CreateStructuredSelector helps us cut down on boilerplate 
  count: getDeviceCountData,
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withStyles(styles)(LandingProjectsListItem));
```

I'd like to use the value to be displayed in `TotalDevicesAvatar`, which is used in the main component:

```
const TotalDevicesAvatar = ( 
     <ListItemAvatar className={classes.devicesAvatar}>
      <>
        <TabletAndroidIcon className={classes.deviceIcon} />
        <Typography variant="caption">**{count}**</Typography>
      </>
    </ListItemAvatar>
  );
  return (
    <ListItem
      className={variation === 'block' ? classes.listItem : ''}
      key={projectId}
      button
      component={Link}
      to={`/${organizationName}/${name}?per_page=10&page=1`}
    >
      {ProjectAvatar}
      <ListItemText
        primary={
          <span
            className={
              variation === 'inline'
                ? classes.inlineListItem
                : classes.projectTitle
            }
          >
            {name}
          </span>
        }
      />
      {TotalDevicesAvatar}
    </ListItem>
  );
```

How can I get the `totalDevices` value for every item? Or for those that `totalDevices` is > 0. This is what I have so far:

```
import { createSelector } from "reselect";
import { deviceCountKey } from './reducer';

// Gets deviceCount state from Redux store 
const getDeviceCountState = ({deviceCount = {} }) => deviceCount;


export const getDeviceCountData = createSelector(
    getDeviceCountState, ????
);
```

Answer (score 0):

By guessing that you need an object as response in sorts of, key being the name and the value is the count

```
{
   'projectId:ed4b4e40-d4e2-4540-8359-c002526f2793': 1
}
```

You can use

```
export const getDeviceCountData = createSelector(
    getDeviceCountState, (state) => 
        Object.entries(state.deviceCount) // here we get an array with the name and value for the object
          .filter(([key, value]) => value.totalDevices > 0) // here we filter out the ones that have 0 total devices
          .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => { // here we create the object and add the name of the project as key and the count as value
            acc[key] = value.totalDevices;
            return acc;
          }, {}));
```

Comment: If you need for all of them, not just for the ones that have device count over 0, remove the `.filter(..)` line

Comment: Thanks! A couple questions. I'm getting an error because of `state`, would it be because I'm using `createStructuredSelector` in mapStateToProps? Also, this is a great way to get all the data in a single object, but is it possible to return one by one? Editing post for more clarity

Comment: I'm not sure why you get the state error. You have to figure that out. 

For getting one by one, you can use an `Object.values(returnedObject).map(el => /* do whatever with the value */)`

Comment: Or instead of doing this you can replace the `.reduce(...)` with `.map(([,val]) => val.totalDevices)` and getting an array instead of object only with the count